# i need to redirect page after particular session count

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, servlet-listeners

I am creating one web application, in that application im creating sessionlistener. In that session listener if condition is not working how to redirect page to another page after reaching particular session count.

```
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;


public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    private int sessionCount = 0;
    HttpServletResponse response;

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {

            sessionCount++; 

            if(sessionCount>=2)
            {

                response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Session Created1: " + event.getSession().getId());



        System.out.println("Total Sessions1: " + sessionCount);



    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {
            sessionCount--;
        }
        System.out.println("Session Destroyed: " + event.getSession().getId());
        System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + sessionCount);
    }
}
```

i map this class file in xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not `redirect` from your `Listener`,for redirection you'll have to write redirection code in `servelet` , `jsp` and `filter`.

**Here's the solution.**

Store `Session_Count` inside `application scope` and check the value of `Session_count` on every web page ,by these two ways.

**a.)** Creating a `Filter` with `\*` `url-pattern` and add redirection code inside it.

OR

**b.)** Including a `common jsp`(that would contains the code for redirection) at top of every other web pages .
Or add the redirection code manually in every web page.

- **Update you Listener**

  public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
      private Integer sessionCount;

  ```
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
      synchronized (this) {
          ServletContext application = event.getSession().getServletContext();
          sessionCount = (Integer) application.getAttribute("SESSION_COUNT");
          if (sessionCount == null) {
              application.setAttribute("SESSION_COUNT", (sessionCount = 1));//setting sessioncount inside application scope
          } else {
              application.setAttribute("SESSION_COUNT", sessionCount + 1);
          }
          System.out.println("Session Created1: "+ event.getSession().getId());
          System.out.println("Total Sessions1: " + sessionCount);
      }
  }

  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
      synchronized (this) {
          ServletContext application = event.getSession().getServletContext();
          sessionCount = (Integer) application.getAttribute("SESSION_COUNT");
          application.setAttribute("SESSION_COUNT", sessionCount - 1);
      }
      System.out.println("Session Destroyed: " + event.getSession().getId());
      System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + sessionCount);
  }
  ```

  }
- **Create a filter** with **`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`** as follows.

  ```
      @WebFilter("/*")
      public class redirectOnSessionCount implements Filter {
      public void destroy() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
          HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
          HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
          Integer sessionCount = (Integer) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("SESSION_COUNT");//fetching session count from application scope
              if(sessionCount!=null && sessionCount>2 && ! httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString().contains("Error.jsp")){
               //httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString().contains("Error.jsp") - > if it's already redirecting to error.jsp then no redirection 
                  httpResponse.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");//redirection code
              }
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }

      public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

  }
  ```
- Mapping inside **`web.xml`** for filter.

  ```
  <filter>
      <filter-name>redirectOnSessionCount</filter-name>
      <filter-class>redirectOnSessionCount</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>redirectOnSessionCount</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  ```

### **Update :-**

- **Without using filter**

Create a `redirectOnSessionCount.jsp` as follows and include this in your all pages at the top or add this code to each web page.

```
<%
Integer sessionCount = (Integer) application.getAttribute("SESSION_COUNT");//fetching session count from application scope
if(sessionCount!=null && sessionCount>2){
    response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");//redirection code
}
%>
```

Comment: Hi vikrant, i dont know exactly what to map in xml file can you please help me. I have 4 jsp files index,adduser,destroy and error. If session count reaches limit it goto error page until one session terminates. I have created class file redirectOnSessionCount.java which you sent me. I dont know what to change in xml because am new to xml file please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Vikrant, my web.xml file I just edit myself.  Is this Correct??  <welcome-file-list><welcome-file> index.jsp </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener><description>sessionListener</description>
<listener-class>
net.viralpatel.servlet.listener.SessionListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter><filter-name>redirectOnSessionCount</filter-name>
<filter-class>redirectOnSessionCount</filter-class>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>redirectOnSessionCount</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>

Comment: Yes it's seems fine :) ,Hey i have made some changes inside filter update your filter too :)

Comment: hi friend, i checked both types using filters and include jsp but both wont work because i set condition sessioncount>2 but it goes more than 2 but it should redirect to error.jsp know

Comment: i didn't get ant error but it exceeds the session limit. I set session limit not more than 2 but it exceeds session limit 2 . if exceeds means it suppose to go error page right

Comment: Is it not redirecting at all ?? after 3 or 4 .. Reduce limit to 1 & check if its redirecting on session count 2,3 or 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61093/discussion-between-vikrant-singh-and-anand).

Comment: hi vikrant. sessioncount dont want to start in index page it starts after login to second page the sessioncount want to start. Is it possible??? If possible can u tell me

Comment: on index page use `<%@ page session="false" %>` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not instantiating response, you are more than likely getting a NPE at the response.sendRedirect statement. A Listener may not be the place to try a redirect.